# copy folders with files with a batch program (Windows)

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, copy

I am blocked in an exercise... We have the next structure:

1) company/companyA/1.KYC/data17-07-05.xls 
2) company/companyB/1.KYC/data17/08/04.xls 
3) company/companyC/1.KYC/data17/08/08.xls & docXLS.xls 
4) etc.

I would like to copy only the folders number 1 and 2 and not the 3... (so only folders where we have 1 file and not 2).

I don't have the idea of how I have to begin...

I have the next code but I am lost:

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

set "folder=%~1"
if not defined folder set "folder=C:\Users\Albert\Desktop\backup2\company01\"

for /d %%a in ("%folder%\*") do (
    set "size=0"
    for /f "tokens=3,5" %%b in ('dir /-c /a /w /s "%%~fa\*" 2^>nul ^| findstr /b /c:"  "') do if "%%~c"=="" set "size=%%~b"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    if !size! GTR 0 xcopy "C:\Users\Albert\Desktop\backup2\company01\"%%~nxa "C:\Users\Albert\Desktop\backup2\"%%~nxa /e /i

    echo(%%~nxa # !size!
    endlocal
)

pause
```

I am a beginner in the batch langage so if it's possible to help me .. Thank a lot !

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If I don't show you what I have tried, it's maybe because I don't have something interesting to show you .. Batch is very difficult for me in windows so I need help and I ask my question to know if a good one can help me because he/she did it before me or if he/she wants to help me

Comment: @AlKural, your file specification is untruthful; `data17/08/04.xls` and `data17/08/08.xls` are not possible filenames because / and \ are disallowed characters.

Comment: You should use something like `for /f %%b in ('dir /B "%%~fa\*" 2^>nul ^| find /c "xls"') Do if "%%b"=="1" xcopy ....` to count the files and only copy if count is one.

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes, as per your specified data, that the `.xls` files will always be in a sub directory named `1.KYC`:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "folder=%~1"
If Not Defined folder Set "folder=%UserProfile%\Desktop\backup2\company01"

If Not Exist "%folder%\" Exit/B
For /F "Delims=|" %%A In ('Dir/B/S/AD-S-L "%folder%\1.KYC"') Do (Set "_="
    For /F "Skip=6Tokens=3" %%B In ('RoboCopy/L /NFL /NDL /NJH "%%A" Null *.xls'
    ) Do If "%%B"=="1" If Not Defined _ (Set "_=T"
        XCopy "%%A" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\backup2\%%~nxA" /E /I))
```

*It does however have a known issue:

The `RoboCopy` command will match any file extensions beginning with `.xls` which means if you wanted it to match a directory containing only one `.xls` file but there was also an `.xlsx` file in there, it will not function as you need.*